# I am trying to use Snowflake function BUILD_SCOPED_FILE_URL however I get 403 error

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to use the function BUILD_SCOPED_FILE_URL on unstructured data(excel sheets). I have uploaded these sheets on Snowflake internal stage and have made use of the Put command to do so.Also to note the stage "hyperion_stage" I created is a default internal stage and no encryption is enabled.

Below are the steps I followed:

//Creating internal stage

create stage hyperion_stage;

//Uploading a test file in the stage
put file:///Users/rshrivastava/Downloads/hlvguide.csv @hyperion_stage/ AUTO_COMPRESS = FALSE;

//I can see the file loaded in the stage.

list @hyperion_stage;

+--------------+--------------+-------------+-------------+--------------------+--------------------+----------+---------+
| source       | target       | source_size | target_size | source_compression | target_compression | status   | message |
|--------------+--------------+-------------+-------------+--------------------+--------------------+----------+---------|
| hlvguide.csv | hlvwfhguide.csv |      183548 |      183552 | NONE               | NONE               | UPLOADED |         |
+--------------+--------------+-------------+-------------+--------------------+--------------------+----------+---------+

//Trying to build the URL using the build_scoped_file_url snowflake function

select build_scoped_file_url(@hyperion_stage,'hlvguide.csv');

I get the below link

https://*******.us-west-2.privatelink.snowflakecomputing.com/api/files//238605147195925253/GVsjFXHq5vE7DVmEjo0Ql2WsLNHXfc6nQ8J5NoCPGZ9f6R8QeunEZtqPtsBiPcA6EmqFW810cWmP3hyom9Ky5ox82eucyUVpemM0FejbfYxYo5Ellq0%2bGqyTiNOHN%2fInH%2bOxNzOKvyJZSU7sy08t%2bubFNNNshoIXTrOz1MkmMm%2fjwxl81MuqPDCK5GEdZr6noiOhOHLbmTQ3QKQMNAZhrm00zjF6lNc%3d

When I try to copy this link and put it in the browser, I am getting 403 forbidden error. I tried with other browser as well and the result is same. Does this works or if I am missing any of the steps above?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3uvc.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting this error is because you need to provide authentication.

Below are the two items you can try:

1>Open snowsight, follow the steps are you described above and click the link within snow sight, you should not see an error.

2> This URL is a rest API that needs authentication.Authenticate to Snowflake via the Snowflake SQL API using OAuth or key pair authentication. Then after you can call this GET URL through curl or any application program.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/sql-api/authenticating.html#label-sql-api-authenticating-key-pair

Happy tshooting!!

Comment: Within Snowsight if I build the URL, I am able to download however what is the use if I copy the URL that is created and put it in browser and it still needs additional authentication as I don't want to use additional process.

Comment: Thank you Tushkar. It works as you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

It's described in the documents:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/build_scoped_file_url.html

> This function generates **a scoped Snowflake-hosted URL** to a staged
> file using the stage name and relative file path as inputs.
>
> You can access files in a stage using either of the following methods:
>
> 1- Retrieve a scoped URL in **Snowsight**. Click on the scoped URL in the results table.
>
> 2- Send the scoped URL in a request to the REST API
> for file support. When users send a scoped URL to the REST API to
> access files, Snowflake performs the following actions:
>
> - Authenticate the user. Verify that it was the current user who called the BUILD_SCOPED_FILE_URL function and generated the scoped
>   URL.
> - Verify that the scoped URL is not expired.
> - Redirect the user to the staged file in the cloud storage service.

This is why you can download the file in Snowsight, and you get "403 Forbidden" message when you try to access it directly.